# Marking unconsidered responses

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When consulting our own profile, we have access to the list of the responses (I think, comments on our answer).

Sometimes, the following scenario happens: I have two or more messages in my inbox, both require some clarifications on my answers. So I click on the inbox, and this one then becomes as if there was no message. Clarifying the first answer may take more time than I expected, and I cannot address the request of the second message. Then there is the risk I do not come back to this request.

What I suggest is the following: in the responses list, mark the comment as "answered" if we made an edit to this question or post a comment (in the same spirit of replied e-mail in a mail box).

In that way, when the described scenario happen, we go the the responses list and address the unanswered requests.

What do you think?

Comment: [Similar Meta.SE feature request.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64283/enable-marking-a-response-as-unread) (It's more than four years old, so I doubt it'll be implemented someday :/ )

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I was not aware of this post. Thanks!

Comment: Davide, you can still click the inbox icon in the top bar. Even though its color has returned to normal, the messages are still there. Of course, for this to help you need to observe that two new messages had arrived, when you first clicked it.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I see. But I am not sure it solves the problem. If the second comment is not replied, the only way I have is to click on the comment and go to the corresponding topic, while it is not needed with the suggestion in the OP.

Comment: When I get >1 messages in the inbox that look like they need my attention, I open all of them in new tabs. Marking the inbox based on edits or follow-up comments is slightly problematic in that many comments don't call for action. By the proposed logic, they would remain forever unread.

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat I understand. But isn't it the analog of an e-mail box: you won't reply to e-mail which say "OK, see you tomorrow." or things like that.

Comment: And yet my gmail account has over 3000 unread messages, because the one line preview is enough information to me that I never actually open the message and it would take me a great deal of time to go and actually open or delete them all at this point.  If someone starts to neglect marking notifications as responded to, unnecessary to respond to, or otherwise, it will start to pile up.

Comment: @JMoravitz In a certain sense I agree. On the other hand, how users use the proposed system is up to them. Personally, I would be really frustrated if my e-mail inbox didn't let me mark e-mails as "unread" after I had read them. However, if it didn't let me do this then perhaps I would be better at replying to e-mails...